# Wait for method's response before continuing without using SJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a method that should return a specific value, and may be called multiple times in one page load. The value this needs to return can only be accessed via S/AJAX, and so after the first time it's found, it's stored in a value for future retrieval.

```
var dynamo = {
    stored_val : 0,
    get : function() {
        if(stored_val === 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'URL'
                success : function(r) {
                    dynamo.stored_val = r;
                    // I want to return this value here now!
                }
            });
        } else {
            return dynamo.stored_val;
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, I want to use `dynamo.get` and have it's return value readily accessible before continuing with the rest of the code. I know about SJAX, but as it's deprecated I'd rather not use it. I looked into jQuery's promises, that allow methods to be deferred until an action has been completed, maybe that can be used here? I've looked into it but couldn't find any way to do it. If it allowed me to do something like:

```
dynamo.get().done(function(r) {
    // everything else here
    // r = the value of dynamo.stored_val after .get() and all AJAX calls within have completed
});
```

Is this possible?

I know I could simply extract the method from `.get()` and use it with callbacks, but there are multiple points in my code which may call `.get()` at any time (based on user-activity) and I don't want to have to write callbacks everywhere.

Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: `I don't want to have to write callbacks everywhere` - either way, you'll have to rewrite your code everywhere

Comment: If I can achieve what I want to, then I can simply write `dynamo.get().done(function1)` or `dynamo.get().done(function2)` etc. Therefore there would be no code-rewriting, as all the AJAX etc is done within the `.get` function. Note how `.get` in this case doesn't take a callback function, that's the way I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Store the request somewhere, so you can return the pending request if it's not completed yet, that way **only** one request is ever made, and the result is cached for later calls to `get()`

```
var dynamo = {
    xhr        : null,
    stored_val : 0,
    get        : function() {
        if( this.stored_val === 0 && this.xhr === null) {
            this.xhr = $.ajax({ url : 'URL', context : this }).always(function(res) {
                this.xhr = null;
                this.stored_val = res;
            })
        } else if (this.xhr === null) {
            this.xhr = (new $.Deferred()).resolve(this.stored_val);
        }
        return this.xhr;
    }
};
```

then you could do

```
dynamo.get().done(fn).fail(err);
```

Answer (score 0):

store the "Promise" in stored_val - then .get will always return the same thing, the "Promise", and you use it like any other Promise ... with `.then` (not sure what `.done` does in jquery, i.e. are there any side effects to the underlying Promise? if not, then use .done instead of .then

```
var dynamo = {
    stored_val : 0,
    get : function() {
        if(dynamo.stored_val === 0) {
            dynamo.stored_val = $.ajax({
                url : 'URL'
            });
        }
        return dynamo.stored_val;
    }
};

dynamo.get().then(function(result) {
    // do something with result
});
```

Personally, I find objects like that a little cumbersome, especially when there's a lot more to them - I prefer to use IIFE for such code

```
var dynamo = (function() {
    var stored_val;
    return {
        get : function() {
            return stored_val = (stored_val === undefined) ? $.ajax({ url : 'URL' }) : stored_val;
        }
    };
}());
```

or even cleaner

```
var dynamo = (function() {
    var stored_val;
    return function() {
        return stored_val = (stored_val === undefined) ? $.ajax({ url : 'URL' }) : stored_val;
    };
}());
```

but then, in this last case, the usage is

```
dynamo().then(...);
```

no need for get(), dynamo is now a function